# How do I run pause my function and resume it after 5 min in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, background-process, delayed-job

I have to send notification to nearest user and wait for 5 min for their response, in case of no response u have to send it to all users. I used thread.spleep(5.min) but it pause my whole program.
I read about background task but they will run after every 5 min but i have to run one part of fuction and then wait for 5 min while other work continues and then run remaining part again.

Comment: You can make use of `delayed_job`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you want to execute after five minutes, put it in a background task.

If you use delayed_job, you can use `run_at` function. It will execute one time only (not every 5 mins).

Example:

```
Notifier.delay(run_at: 5.minutes.from_now).signup(@user)
```

Comment: Do i have to write delayjob in seprate file or i can use function of same class 
self.delay(run_at: 5.minutes.from_now).myfunc(myobj)

can I do this?

Comment: No need to create separate file. You can directly call like this - @user.delay.activate!(@device).